# When running terraform from Gitlab CI, terraform asks me for the "The address of the REST endpoint"

Tags: terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

When I run `terraform apply` using the Terraform files in my GitLab CI Pipeline (I didn't write them) I get the following,

```
Initializing the backend...
address
  The address of the REST endpoint
```

Can these files be run in isolation of GitLab CI, on a workstation with vanilla terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a part of the provider, `backend "http"`, which is like this somewhere

```
terraform {
  backend "http" {
  }
  ...
```

This is how you configure [Terraform State as a backend in GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/terraform_state.html#initialize-a-terraform-state-as-a-backend-by-using-gitlab-cicd). This is need so your tfstate file doesn't remain on the runner. This is what's responsible for updating that tfstate file remotely.

If running them outside of GitLab CI just delete the backend provider.